Old western movie or serial, Indian attack, trap door, boy in uniform
Long ago, probably in the 1970s, I saw a few scenes from a live action movie, movie serial, or TV series on American television.  I think I saw it on a black and white TV set, and so don't know if it was in color.
I suspect that it was an old movie or movie serial dating from the 1930s or 1940s, and thus it would have been in black and white.
If my memory is correct there was a scene where hostile Indian warriors were attacking a stockaded western fort, riding around it.  A woman and a boy were in the relative safety of one of the log cabins in the fort.  And then a trap door in the floor opened and Indians started crawling out of some secret passageway.
I suspect it was the cliffhanger ending of a chapter of a movie serial. 
I have seen a bunch of western movies with Indian attacks on forts.
Fury at Furnace Creek (1948).
Two Flags West (1950).
I Killed Geronimo (1950).
Only the Valiant (1951).
Taza, son of Cochise (1954).
Fort Dobbs (1958).
Fort Bowie (1958).
The Oregon Trail (1959).
And I don't think that scene was in any of them.
Another thing I think I remember about that scene is that the boy seemed to be wearing a 19th century US military uniform.
In real life a lot of school uniforms resembled military uniforms.  I have seen a photo of a thirteen year old relative from 1871 wearing what looked like a Civil War uniform, the uniform of the Nazareth Hall Academy. And at Penn State University I once saw a photo of an early ROTC class wearing what looked like Civil War uniforms.
But there actually were some boys in the 19th century US army.  Some of the musicians - drummers, fifers, buglers and trumpeters - in the Civil War volunteers and the regular army that fought Indians were teen age and even grade school age. Considering how much movies tend to exaggerate, and the fact that many old westerns were made for kids, it is a little surprising that there weren't teenage or younger buglers in half the cavalry westerns that were made.
In fact there have been a couple of movies with boy buglers as the protagonists: The Bugler Call (1916), starring William Collier Jr. (1902-1987) and The Bugle Call (1927) starring Jackie Coogan (1914-1984).  They are silent films and I think both are lost films I could not possibly have seen.
I have seen End of the Trail (1932) in which Captain Tim Travers (Tim McCoy) has a son "Sonny" (Wally Albright 1925-1999) who wears a soldier's uniform and corporal's stripes despite being a civilian.
I am also familiar with The Adventures of Rin Tin Tin (1954-1959) with honorary corporal Rusty (Lee Aakar born 1943) who wore a uniform.  As you can see from photos, Rusty usually wore a light colored shirt with a double row of buttons.
If I remember right, the boy in the scene I remember wore a dark colored military jacket with a single row of buttons.
I also remember seeing the TV movie Female artillery (1973) and that was different.
I suspect it could be the serial Custer's Last Stand (1936).  It obviously involves hostile Indians and has a boy actor, Bobby Nelson (I) (1922-1974).  In this still he has a bugle, though he is wearing buckskins instead of a uniform.
http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0027488/mediaviewer/rm20051458561
Of course many other western movies and serials were made that I am not familiar with.

I did watch Custer's Last Stand on YouTube according to Jan Doggen's suggestion.  By the time of the 10th episode I was getting to think the scene wasn't in the serial.  
Then villain Tom "Keen" Blade sneaked into Fort Reed along with his Sioux ally Young Wolf through an underground passage that led to a trapdoor in Blade's old Cantina building.  Young Wolf freed two Sioux braves from the guard house.  Blade shot a Sioux about to testify against him and they left through the secret tunnel.  The Sioux chiefs left and attacked the fort.  
As Sioux attacked from the outside, some warriors used the underground passage and trap door to enter the fort and attack from inside. As Mr.s Custer sat at the General's desk in his office, Young Wolf crept in behind her and raised his tomahawk or war club to strike her for the cliffhanger at the end of the 10th episode.
So it turns out my memory got most things right and a few things wrong and I did correctly deduce where I saw the scene.
